# How can I update a part of an element of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Backstory: I'm a web guy with very little OOP teaching in college. Now I'm tossed into a "Java in a week" work training session trying to float.

I need to take an ArrayList with each element having these four "attributes(?)": Name, ProductID, Price, Expiration Date. I want to allow a user to choose which element they would like to update, then which "attribute" of that element they would like to update. I thought for a while ArrayList.set(index,element) would work, however now I think that will update the entire element, not just the Price or just the Name if desired.

Some of my code:

```
ArrayList < Prod > pList = new ArrayList < Prod > ();
pList.add(new Prod("Tomato", "P101", 10, "4 days"));
//etc etc

int index = 0;
for (Prod p: pList)
{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Index : " + String.valueOf(index++));
    System.out.println("Name : " + p.getName());
    System.out.println("ID : " + p.getId());
    System.out.println("Price : " + p.getPrice());
    System.out.println("Expiration Date : " + p.getExpDate());
}

Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.println("Which Index would you like to adjust?");
int change = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("What would you like to change about Index " + change + "?");
System.out.println("Enter 1 for the Name.");
System.out.println("Enter 2 for the Product ID.");
System.out.println("Enter 3 for the Price.");
System.out.println("Enter 4 for the Expiration Date.");
int type = input.nextInt();

if (type == 1)
{
    System.out.println("What would you like to change the name to?");
    String newName = input.nextLine();
    pList.set(change, newName);
}
```

I do have setters and getters and the works all properly set up  and can compile; the issue is how to adjust the name, or PID, etc. I believe this is very specific and not general like the intro to asking questions here requested, however I don't know how else to solve this; I've been working on it for hours.

Comment: 1. Get the desired element to update, you will get the object reference. 2. Update the contents of this object reference, the changes will be *reflected* on the object inside the ArrayList.

Comment: if you want to update the object in a list, you should get that object first and do the changes in the object.

Read basic principle of Java : Copy by reference in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Which Index would you like to adjust?");
int change = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("What would you like to change about Index " + change + "?");
System.out.println("Enter 1 for the Name.");
System.out.println("Enter 2 for the Product ID.");
System.out.println("Enter 3 for the Price.");
System.out.println("Enter 4 for the Expiration Date.");
int type = input.nextInt();
Prod p = pList.get(change);

if(type==1){ 
   p.setName(input.nextLine());
}
else if(type==2){
   p.setId(input.nextLine());
}
///and so on
```

Comment: At time of my comment there are 5 answers. I have only attempted this one and I believe it has solved my problem. I had the .set(index,element) stuck in my head, it didn't even cross my mind to use the setter. I'll try to fully implement this solution tomorrow. Thank you for prompt responses!

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Which Index would you like to adjust?");
int change = input.nextInt();

Prod product = pList.get(change);

if(type==1){
   System.out.println("What would you like to change the name to?");
   String newName = input.nextLine();
   product.setName(newName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the element at index `change` and call the relevant setter, eg:

```
Prod p = pList.get(change);
switch (type)
{
    case 1:
        p.setName(newName);
        break;
    case 2:
        p.setProductId(newName);
        break;
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch the object at the index and try to update the same then it should work. Something like this:

```
//Fetch the prod need to be updated
Prod prodToUpdate = pList.get(index);
//update the attributes of the fetched prod like this
prodToUpdate.setName("updatedName");
```

Comment: I don't think you need this part pList.set(index,prodToUpdate);

If you update the object, it will be automatically reflected in List since Java uses references

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `pList.get(change).setName()` to update the particular field of the Prod object.